# Give an example where Kummer test fails

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Statement of Kummer's test :
  If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$  and  $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$ are two infinite series of positive real numbers such that $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$ is divergent, then 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} w_n=\begin{cases} l>0, & \text{convergent}\\
l <0, & \text{divergent}\\
l =0, & \text{inconclusive}
\end{cases}
 $$
 where $\; w_n=\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}b_n-b_{n+1}\right).$

Let us consider $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}=\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$.

Then $\; w_n=\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}b_n-b_{n+1}\right)=\frac{n+1}{n}\rightarrow 1 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Now the $p$ series($p=2$),  $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$  is divergent.

Give an example, where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$ is divergent and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is also divergent but,
$\lim w_n=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited) An example where $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_n}$ is divergent and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is also divergent, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} w_n=1$, is not possible if $b_n>0\;\;(n=1,2,...),$ since this would violate Kummer's test. An example is possible if the condition $b_n>0\;\;(n=1,2,...)$, which is a requirement of Kummer's test, is dropped. For instance, let $a_n=1$ and $b_n=-n$ for $n=1,2,...\;$.

Comment: @JB, thank you very much. +1 for you

Comment: How can I choose $\{b_n\}_n$  such that $b_n>0$ satisfying  $\lim w_n=1$.

Comment: @MTMA: See my revised answer.